# Foreach loop stores only first index of multidimensional array | Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-excel

I'm trying to save multidimensional array values into separate strings and store them in the database. I have the following array:
My response data:

```
[
  {
        "name": "bla bla",
        "creator": "bla bla",
        "cost": 200
    }, {
        "name": "bla bla",
        "creator": "bla bla",
        "cost": 200
    },
    {
        "name": "bla bla",
        "creator": "bla bla",
        "cost": 200
     }
  ]
```

I have tried single foreach loops (like below), this code is currently working but only accepts (save) only the first index. I have almost 10K of data. I need it to return results for each array values.

```
public function fileImport(Request $request) 
{   
    set_time_limit(6000);
    $array = (new DrugsImport)->toArray($request->file('file'));
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($array as $item) {
        $drugs = new Drug;
        $drugs->user_id = 1;
        $drugs->name = $item[$i]['name'];
        $drugs->cost = $item[$i]['cost'];
        $drugs->save();
        //$name = utf8_decode($item[$i]['naimenovaniya']);
        // $name = $item[$i]['naimenovaniya'];
        // iconv("Windows-1251", "UTF-8", $name);
        $i++;
    }
    return response()->json($drugs);

   //Excel::import(new DrugsImport, $request->file('file')->store('temp'));
   //return back();
}
```

Currently, this code stores only the first [0] element. The remaining values are not saved. I’ve also tried using a few other ways but in all of the first element stored.
I tried also like this:

```
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if (is_array($value)) {
        ......
    }
}
```

I can't find where I'm wrong. Can anyone help?
Thank you!

**EDITED**
If i run using `var_dump($array)`:

```
    array(1) {
        [0] => array(2897) {
                [0] => array(3) {
                    ["name"] => string(36)
                    "bla bla bla" ["cost"] => int(200)
                } [1] => array(3) {
                     ["name"] => string(36)
                    "bla bla bla" ["cost"] => int(200)
                } [2] => array(3) {
                     ["name"] => string(36)
                    "bla bla bla" ["cost"] => int(200)
                } [3] => array(3) {
                     ["name"] => string(36)
                    "bla bla bla" ["cost"] => int(200)
                }
        ....
```

**UPDATED**
My DrugsImport file:

```
    class DrugsImport implements ToModel, WithHeadingRow
{
    use Importable;

    /**
    * @param array $row
    *
    * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
    */
    public function model(array $row)
    {
        return new Drug([
            'name '     => $row[0],
            'cost'    => $row[1]
        ]);
    }

}
```

if I dump $array it returns like that:

```
array:1 [▼
0 => array:2897 [▼
0 => array:3 [ …3]
1 => array:3 [ …3]
2 => array:3 [ …3]
3 => array:3 [ …3]
4 => array:3 [ …3]
....
```

> Sorry if it's a duplicate question, but none of them worked ...

Comment: If `$array` is what you posted first, then `$item[$i]['name']` should throw a warning about undefined index. `$item` will be the sub array so it should only be `$item['name']`. No need for the `$i` at all.

Comment: You also have a typo: `['cose']` should be `['cost']`

Comment: No if I use `$index['name']` it returne an error `Undefined index: name`.

Comment: what do you see if you dump the array before the loop? ```dump($array)```

Comment: Then the array doesn't look like the one you've posted. Here's a demo: https://3v4l.org/LlTXC

Comment: If I use without loop, all the array elements are fully visible. If i use loop it return only first [0] element.

Comment: We can't help if we don't have the correct info. Before the foreach, do a `print_r($array);` and add the output to your question.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I edited the question, I added dump result.

Comment: That doesn't look like the one you've posted. This shows that you have one array that contains one array that contains multiple arrays (3 levels). Try: `foreach ($array[0] as $item)` and still only use `$item['name']` inside the foreach.

Comment: Show me the DrugImport file

Comment: @MagnusEriksson thanks, but if I use `foreach ($array[0] as $item)`, it returned only last element of array.

Comment: The "new" output looks like it's from the console (outputted through JS)? Can you please do a `var_dump($array)` or `var_dump($array)` to show us how it looks right before the foreach? The arrays you've shown doesn't match the issues you get.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I edited the question with `var_dump()` result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, there are a few issues with your code.

#### The format

Your array is an array that contains one array that contains multiple arrays, so if you only do:

```
foreach ($array as $item)
```

it will only iterate it once (since `$array` only contains one array), which is why you only got the first.

If you do

```
foreach ($array[0] as $item)
```

and use `$item['name']`, it will iterate through all items.

#### Why does it only return the last?

That's because you're overwriting the `$drugs` variable on each iteration.

If you want to return them all, add them to an array instead. This should do it:

```
// Define the array where we will add the drugs so we can return them all
$listOfDrugs = [];

foreach ($array[0] as $item) {
    $drug = new Drug;
    $drug->user_id = 1;
    $drug->name = $item['name'];
    $drug->cost = $item['cost'];
    $drug->save();       

    // Add the new drug to the array so it can be returned after the loop
    $listOfDrugs[] = $drug;
}

// Now return the array with all the drugs
return response()->json($listOfDrugs);
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try like this.
let we know if you get an error

```
// controller fileImport     
public function fileImport(Request $request) 
{   
   $drug = new DrugsImport;
   Excel::import($drug, $request->file('file'));
   return $drug->drugResult;
} 

// Drug Import 
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToCollection;
class DrugsImport implements ToCollection, WithHeadingRow
{
      public $drugResult;
      public function collection(Collection $rows)
      {
          $this->drugResult = $rows;
      }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this way works, but I need a different way. I need to do the necessary actions on the values inside the array (Split, trim, etc.). This must be done import in the  controller.

Comment: what do you mean necessary actions ? i can't understand

Comment: Sorry, my English is not very good, I have to delete some values in the array, I need to edit the values, so it was necessary in the controller.